# Parsing array from dynamic form to script

Tags: php

I am generating a dynamic order form in php based on varying search criteria from data in a MySQL database.
The order form is in effect a line-item list and could have several hundred line-items.
Each line-item will have the following data (simulated names) :
Row# ItemID ItemName Units/Pack Price/Unit.
In addition to the above data extracted from the database, I am adding 2 dynamic fields :
1. a check box to identify items to order
2. a text box to enter the qty ordered

```
<?php
$row=0;
while($item = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$row++;
$id     = "$item[ProductID]";
$name       = "$item[Name]";
$units      = "$item[PerPack]";
$price      = "$item[Price]";

echo "<tr>
    <td align='center'>$row</td>
    <td align='center'>$id</td>
    <td>$name</td>
    <td align='center'>$units</td>
        <td align='center'>$price</td>
    <td align='center'><input type=checkbox id=$row name=ReviewID[] value='$id' /></td>
        <td align='center'><input type=text size=3 maxlength=3 id=$row name=ReviewQty[] /></td>
    </tr>";
    }
?>
```

The order form is then processed by an order review script.
After much searching and experimenting I have come up with the following script.

```
<?php
$keys_array = $_POST['ReviewID'];
$keys_count = count($keys_array);

$values_array = array_filter($_POST['ReviewQty']);
$values_count = count($values_array);

$order_array = array_combine($keys_array, $values_array);

if($keys_count != $values_count){
$status = 'Error';
$error_message = "ORDER Quatities Mismatch";}

// html code omitted
if($status == 'Error') echo $error_message;
//html code omitted
if($keys_count != $values_count) exit();
//html code omitted
    while (list ($key, $val) = each ($order_array))
    { 
    echo "<tr>
            <td align='center'>...</td>
            <td align='center'>$key</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <td align='center'>...</td>
            <td align='center'>...</td>
            <td align='center'>...</td>
            <td align='center'>$val</td>
            </tr>";
    }
?>
```

The problem with my solution is that is does not check that each selected checkbox has a corresponding qty value in the same row.
In other words if I check any 5 boxes and enter values in any 5 text boxes, it will pass the test.

I need a check which verifies the checkbox is in the same row (line-item) as the qty value.
It would also be great if I could parse all the line-item data for a selected checkbox, otherwise I would need to do another MySQL query in the review script.

I am having trouble getting an array with 2 values per key to work.
Any help/improvements would be appreciated.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW by experimentation I found that by using the row number as the key, I can match keys and do a cross-check the arrays that both have the same keys.

```
<td align='center'><input type=checkbox name=ReviewID[$row] value='$id' /></td>
<td align='center'><input type=text size=3 maxlength=3 name=ReviewQty[$row] /></td>
```

I can also parse the other data via hidden fields in separate arrays once again with the row number as keys.

```
<td align='center'>$price</td><input type=hidden name=ReviewPrice[$row] value='$price' />
```

All I have to do now is match key values, then I can pull up only the data I need.

I am still interested in any better solutions, o/wise I hope someone else finds this useful - I know I really struggled to get to this point.